# How to see RGB and XYZ image info in Blender 2.8?

Tags: image, color-management

Where is the rendered image info in Blender 2.8?

An example screenshot I found from Blender Artists highlights some info near the blue cube in the rendered image.  In previous versions of Blender there was a status bar with handy image info showing XYZ and RGB data.

[image: Blender 2.79 example render]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Image editor, If you Right click on the image, you can sample the pixels of the image. A small window appears at the bottom of the screen where you can read the pixel information.

(for previous versions of blender: left click on the UV/Image editor window)

[image]

From Left to right you see:

**$X$** (horizontal) and **$Y$** (vertical) pixel position ($0$,$0$ is at the bottom left of the screen)

**Z** depth, in blender units.

**R**ed, **G**reen, **B**lue, **A**lpha information before the color management transforms (Scene Referred, Linear values).

**R**ed, **G**reen, **B**lue after the Color Management transforms (Display Referred, values)

**H**ue

**S**aturation

**V**alue

**L**uminance

Comment: Are you sure this works for Blender 2.8?  When I right click on an image I just get an empty context menu.  Maybe I should try getting a newer beta version?

Comment: The image was made on 2.8. As you know 2.8 is in Beta, thus changing constantly. Use the latest version.

Comment: I updated to the latest Beta and the right-click 'Sample Color' now works in the UV Editor, but not in the `Rendering` tab with my old file opened.  However, it works everywhere when I start a new file.  Obviously some bug hiding out...  I'm accepting this answer as it _is_ correct. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are in "image editor" and not in "uv editor" window (editor type).
I was strugling with it too.