# Is there anyway to show values in Blender Eevee like in Redshift?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

In Redshift render view you can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to check the float type value of every pixel, it's very convenient to toggle parameters in some info nodes like fresnel, AO, etc. But I don't know how to do the same in Blender

[image]

In Redshift you can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to see the real value of every pixel

[image]

See if you wanna get the real value of now this B&W map in Render View, how to do that? B&W map of Info channels always cheats, you know.

Comment: In the render window `F12`, you can hold down the right mouse button to get the color values. I'd suggest enable Node Wrangler which allows to `Ctrl`+`Shift`-click any node to get it rendered. You might want to down the samples to a lower value like `5` in this case: [How to see RGB and XYZ image info in Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/134634/31447)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see RGB and XYZ image info in Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134634/how-to-see-rgb-and-xyz-image-info-in-blender-2-8)

Comment: Thanks, Timaroberts! I will have a try!